# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library, Windows, Apache 2.2, php 5.2.11

Tags: php, windows, apache

This is becoming a very frustrating issue. I am trying to do a clean install of apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.11. Everything seems to be configured correctly but the php modules aren't starting...

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '.;C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/php/ext/php_mcrypt.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '.;C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/php/ext/php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '.;C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/php/ext/php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

in the php.ini

```
include_path = ".;C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\php"
extension_dir = ".;C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/php/ext/"
```

All the files are there... The .dll files such as ssleay32.dll, libmcrypt.dll, libmysql.dll, libeay32.dll  are all installed at...

C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/php/

I also included them in the C:\Windows\System32

and even added C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/php/ to the windows path.

I have no idea why this isn't working and it feels like a no win situation. Anyone have any ideas on how to get this all working ok?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension_dir = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/php/ext/"
```

without starting with the `.;`

Comment: That got it all working again. now I just have to figure out why OpenSSL and paypalewp aren't working right even after a clean install... Thanks for the answer

Comment: Happy to help!
Post another question about your OpenSSL issues if you cant solve it. Maybe someone around here can help. :)

Answer (score 9):

You just uncomment the extension_dir in php.ini

[image]

Comment: On Windows, Apache 2.4 does not understand relative paths (at least to my knowledge). I use an absolute path here.

Answer (score 2):

Just for my future self if no-else. This is with PHP 5.2.13 running in Windows on IIS 8.

I got the following error:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

From `phpinfo()` the loaded php.ini file was `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini`.

The extension directory:

```
extension_dir ="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext"
```

These were the last two lines of the `php.ini` file:

```
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension=php_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc6.dll
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

The `php_openssl.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc6.dll` files are in the `ext` directory. The `php_openssl.dll` isn't corrupt (it's the same file size as one on another machine that's working).

PHP will find the sqlsrv dll but not the openssl dll. No idea why. No amounts of IIS restarting did anything.

The solution until I know better was to install the openssl.dll extension using the Windows PHP installer. You can re-run the installer and select 'Change' and it allows you to add or remove libraries. I can't see any difference in the file or the php.ini file now, but now the file loads.

I suspect actually that my problem was similar to this [comment about OpenSSL installation on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php#106115):

> At this point, when you start Apache it will attempt to load php_openssl.dll, but if your setup is anything like mine you will see an error. I prefer to start Apache manually, and the error appears in a dialog box: "The ordinal 4114 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY32.dll". (I'm not sure whether you would get this message if you started Apache as a service). The Apache log also contains an error message saying that php_openssl.dll cannot be loaded, though that message doesn't name libeay32.dll. Welcome to DLL Hell.
>
> Libeay32.dll enters the picture because php_openssl.dll depends on it (and also on ssleay32.dll). What I think happens is that Apache first tries to load php_openssl.dll programmatically from the path specified by the extension_dir key. But then, the loading of the so-called dependent DLLs is left to Windows' default mechanism. If Windows finds an incompatible version of a dependent DLL, you get the error.

I noticed errors about `ssleay32.dll` when trying to run `php -i` from the command line. I just assumed that it didn't have it in the environment. IIS made no mention of any `ssleay32.dll` errors in its logs.

Comment: Yes! it worked. I've run Apache from cmd with `x:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d x:/xampp/apache` command copied from Task Manager, column `command line`). It threw errors for both DLLs. I had to copy `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` from php dir to apache\bin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had same errors, but instead of copying files added php folder to system path and restated the server.

Comment: I agree with you. The PHP docs says: "Although copying DLL files from the PHP folder into the Windows system directory also works (because the system directory is by default in the system's PATH), this is not recommended." 
Since i did not want the PHP binaries on my PATH for everything, i wrote a start script for my Apache HTTPD and added the PHP path only there with a SET PATH=%PATH%;<PHP_PATH>

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 have a bib problem with system PATH names what cannot editable with the general editor because this line is too long......and for PHP module extension good loading must to define PHP path in the system enviroments.

**ONLY one thing helped for me:
https://rix0rrr.github.io/WindowsPathEditor/**