# Laravel 4 installation with composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I wanted to try out the Laravel 4 but, unfortunately, got stuck at the very beginning. When I try to install it using composer as mentioned in the Laravel 4 documentation, I get the following error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "http://nodeload.github.com/laravel/laravel/zip/v4.0.5" file could not
>   be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket
>   transport "SSL" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

I have PHP 5.5.0 with OpenSSL 0.9.8x running on a Mountain Lion 10.8.4. Does anyone have a clue how on earth I can fix this?

I have tried googling through all of the dark corners of the internet, 2006 forums but to no avail......

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Edit your php.ini file and add

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and then restart the apache and your ssl should be detected.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Well, i have tried that but then i get the error saying that php_openssl.dll could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAMP you should edit php.ini in your Apache folder.
for some reason composer uses that php.ini instead of php.ini stored in php folder.

Comment: To quote myself:
"...I have PHP 5.5.0 with openssl 0.9.8x running on a Mountain Lion 10.8.4..."

Comment: after removing ; from extension=php_openssl.dll you should restart server.

Comment: Of course i restarted apache... and then i got error saying php_openssl.dll could not be found.

Comment: do you have two php.ini file? one in apache folder and one in php folder?

Comment: phpinfo() says the loaded one is located at "/etc/php.ini" and the php --ini says its "/usr/local/lib/php.ini"

Comment: ok then enable extension=php_openssl.dll in both and restart and try again.

Comment: As i already said, when i enable dll it says it cannot be found...........

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_openssl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Comment: in the php.ini find extension_dir and check the address is correct. you can also try removing ".;".

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808442/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-windows-apache-2-2-php-5-2-11)

Comment: I don't get it... I don't have ".;" anywhere in my error? Nor in my php.ini? And why is extension_dir relevant here? It says in the error itself nicely: '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_openssl.dll' and that path is correct, just there is not anything like "php_openssl.dll" inside that folder. And i am running a Mac OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.4, not a Windows and certainly not a WAMP...

Comment: Try `$ openssl version` to ensure that it's accessible from the command line.

Comment: sorry I don't have access to your system so i should consider any possible causes. I think you should compile your php with PHP --with-openssl[=DIR]. more information [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php)