# Startup unable to load dynamic library php_openssl.dll

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I want to send an email using localhost (XAMPP). When i added this line "extension=php_openssl.dll" to php.ini  a warning was diplayed saying that "PHP startup: unable to load dynamic library php_openssl.dll". What does it mean?

Comment: Maybe it's the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808442/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-windows-apache-2-2-php-5-2-11

Comment: Does the php_openssl.dll exist in your PHP extensions directory?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop apache
2. Copy `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from `installdir/php/` to:

   - `C:\Windows\System32`
   - `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` ( if x64 bit windows OS)
   - `apache_install_dir\bin`
3. restart apache.