# Installing Composer OpenSSL Issue

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, composer-php

I am trying to install `composer` however when I go to install it  I get this error:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

I currently have `php 5.4.31` and I am running `WAMP2.2` I've checked my `php.ini` file in the `bin/php/php5.4.31/` and ensured that the following line is uncommented:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

The error still resolves and I'm at a loss as to how I can fix it. As I thought by uncommenting the line it would be enabled.

Also when I run this command in the terminal window `php --ini` I get the following message:

`PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found`

Comment: Be sure that the requested dll file is at the correct location. As you can see the error is that the file cannot be located. Also be sure that the apache server under the wamp is supporting ssl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library, Windows, Apache 2.2, php 5.2.11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808442/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-windows-apache-2-2-php-5-2-11)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Javacadabra, extensions like php_openssl.dll will be under php/ext/ directory, you could fix this path in the config file or you could copy that specific file from php/ext directory to php directory.

in your case it will be c:\php\ext

Comment: I will accept this answer, composer installed but for some reason it's commands are not being recognized on the command line, im guessing this is also a path issue.

Comment: @Javacadabra - [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

Answer (score 56):

If you are a windows user, make sure to uncomment this line in your php.ini file:

```
 extension_dir = "ext"
```

It makes sure that PHP is taking the extension from its own ext library.

Comment: This is a great gotcha for windows users.

Answer (score 0):

Quick check list for those who face same issue:

`Before any step if you have any apache running with this PHP version, stop it.`

1. In directory of exact php version check if you have "php.ini" sometimes it's missing so you can just copy "php.ini-development" and rename it to "php.ini".
2. Check if extension is uncommented in "php.ini" - look for
3. `;extension=openssl` and remove ";" from start of line
4. Check if your path to extension in php.ini is correct (one of line with "extension_dir" should be uncommented - without ";" at start of line

```
; https://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
;extension_dir = "ext"
```

5. Double check if your enviourment variable in "PATH" have correct path to exact php variable (sometimes it could be changed for example due to project which require diffrent version)